# Rotate node with gestures or touch event Sceneform AR Core

Tags: android, arcore, sceneform

I am using AR Core as a 3D Viewer in my application. I am not using Sceneform for AR rendering but for rendering the model in 3D. The problem I am facing is how I can 360 rotate the model with swipe gestures or touch events. Is that possible with sceneform or I need to use the more difficult ways like open GL.

Here is my code.

```
public class FullDegreeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

SceneView sceneView;
Scene scene;
Node node;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_full_degree);
    inIt();
    renderObject();
}

private void inIt() {
    sceneView = findViewById(R.id.scene_view);
    scene = sceneView.getScene();
}

private void renderObject() {
    ModelRenderable.builder().setSource(this, Uri.parse("edited.sfb"))
            .build().thenAccept(modelRenderable -> {
                addNodeToScene(modelRenderable);
            }
    ).exceptionally(throwable -> {

        return null;
    });
}

private void addNodeToScene(ModelRenderable renderable) {
    node = new Node();
    node.setParent(scene);
    node.setLocalPosition(new Vector3(0f, 0f, -1f));
    node.setLocalScale(new Vector3(1f, 1f, 1f));
    node.setName("Dog");
    node.setRenderable(renderable);
    TransformableNode transformableNode = new TransformableNode(sceneView.getTransformationSystem());
    transformableNode.setParent(node);
    transformableNode.setLocalRotation(Quaternion.axisAngle(new Vector3(1f, 0, 0), 0f));
    transformableNode.setRenderable(renderable);
    transformableNode.select();
    scene.addChild(transformableNode);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    sceneView.pause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    try {
        sceneView.resume();
    } catch (CameraNotAvailableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: do you have the solution for this, I am stuck on this it would be very helpful if you can share the details

Answer (score 3):

I share my fresh experience, maybe someone still need a solution.

You have two options to achieve that:

1. As noticed above you can implement your own gestures, scales and rotations 
   using androids standard gestures or addOnPeekTouchListener listener of scene.
2. Use Transformable node for it's facilities, then you only have to remove the translation controller and implement a new rotation controller.

*Lets consider option 2 in bit detail with Kotlin code*

Crate new rotation controller for Drag gestures:

```
class DragRotationController(transformableNode: BaseTransformableNode, gestureRecognizer: DragGestureRecognizer) :
    BaseTransformationController<DragGesture>(transformableNode, gestureRecognizer) {

    // Rate that the node rotates in degrees per degree of twisting.
    var rotationRateDegrees = 0.5f

    public override fun canStartTransformation(gesture: DragGesture): Boolean {
        return transformableNode.isSelected
    }

    public override fun onContinueTransformation(gesture: DragGesture) {

        var localRotation = transformableNode.localRotation

        val rotationAmountX = gesture.delta.x * rotationRateDegrees
        val rotationDeltaX = Quaternion(Vector3.up(), rotationAmountX)
        localRotation = Quaternion.multiply(localRotation, rotationDeltaX)

        transformableNode.localRotation = localRotation
    }

    public override fun onEndTransformation(gesture: DragGesture) {}
}
```

To remove translation controller:

```
node.translationController.isEnabled = false
node.removeTransformationController(translationController)
```

Add our custom rotation controller to node

```
val dragRotationController = DragRotationController(node, transformationSystem.dragRecognizer)
node.addTransformationController(dragRotationController)
```

And this is the DragTransformableNode

```
import com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.TransformableNode
import com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.TransformationSystem

class DragTransformableNode(transformationSystem: TransformationSystem) :
    TransformableNode(transformationSystem) {

    private val dragRotationController = DragRotationController(
        this,
        transformationSystem.dragRecognizer
    )

    init {
        translationController.isEnabled = false
        removeTransformationController(translationController)
        removeTransformationController(rotationController)
        addTransformationController(dragRotationController)
    }
}
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to be working.  can't found addTransformationController method.

Comment: @NoumanCh your node must to be TransformableNode to have addTransformationController method

Comment: we had a addTransformChangedListener for transformableNode but don't have addTransformationController.

Comment: @NoumanCh yes it protected function in BaseTransformableNode, you have to extend and implement from TransformableNode, as I done it in my DragRotationController, i will update my answer.

Comment: hey, I have attached DragTransformableNode cod to my answer

Comment: Hi @Tigran , I want to rotate the node with a single finger and I also need dragging. How can I achieve this?

Comment: @NoumanCh, code presented by me is for rotating with single finger

Comment: yes buddy but I need dragging as well. drag with single finger + rotate with single finger.

Comment: you can send it to me on chnouman200@gmail.com or at https://www.linkedin.com/in/muhammad-nouman-android-dev/.

Comment: if I understand this right, your `node` is a `DragTransformableNode`? Weird cause for me it complains about `addTransformationController` and `removeTransformationController` being protected methods so I can't use them...

Comment: How can we make this rotate along the Y and Z axes as well?

Answer (score -1):

You can do it easily with Sceneform. In fact you don't any Sceneform code for it. You just use Android's standard gesture recognition to detect the gesture and use it to update the rotation of your node. https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector

Answer (score -2):

I think that your implementation is pretty close to how it should work. Just take a look at the hellosceneform example from Google (https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/blob/master/samples/hellosceneform/app/src/main/java/com/google/ar/sceneform/samples/hellosceneform/HelloSceneformActivity.java).